# Powerquery IN operator in conditional column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

How this m Power BI M code can be modified

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStep", "Tag", each 
     if Text.Contains([Column1]) = "value1" then "bingo" 
else if Text.Contains([Column1]) = "value2" then "bingo"
else if Text.Contains([Column1]) = "value3" then "bingo"
else ["Some other value"])
```

into a one line code similar to SQL

```
case when [Column1] in ("value1", "value2", "value3") then "bingo" else "Some other value" end
```

I would not like to repeat the lines `else if` but have it in a similar way as

```
List.Contains({'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'}, [Column1])
```

used here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51749519/1903793

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [List.Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/list-transform) to generate the [Text.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/text-contains) function call, then use [List.AnyTrue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/list-anytrue) to check if `Column1` contains any of the text.

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"PreviousStep", "Tag", each if List.AnyTrue(List.Transform({"value1", "value2", "value3"}, (s) => Text.Contains([Column1], (s)))) then "bingo" else "Some other value")
```

Results:

[image]

[Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/1c898f9b-5c7d-45b3-8b22-f58611e7bd1e/text-contains-any-of?forum=powerquery)

Comment: Thanks. The one line solution looks complex. Really no simpler way?

Answer (score 4):

### If you want to compare whole word, you should use `List.ContainsAny` function

```
let
    haystack = #table({"col"}, {{"qwer"}, {"asdf"}, {"zxcv"}, {"zxwecv"}, {"other"}}),
    needles = {"qwer", "zxcv"},
    add = Table.AddColumn(haystack, "Tag", each if List.ContainsAny(needles, {[col]}) then "bingo" else "Some other value")
in
    add
```

### But if you search a part of word, the answer becomes a little more complicated

```
let
    haystack = #table({"col"}, {{"qwer"}, {"asdf"}, {"zxcv"}, {"zxwecv"}, {"other"}}),
    needles = {"we", "as"},
    add = Table.AddColumn(haystack, "Tag", each if List.MatchesAny(needles, (s)=>Text.Contains([col], s)) then "bingo" else "Some other value")
in
    add
```

Comment: Your solution for part of phrase looks very similar to Foxan Ng answer `(s) => Text.Contains([Column1], (s))`. Would you explain the difference?

Comment: The difference is that Foxan Ng makes two evaluations - 1) transforms list to true/false if item contains text passing check-function, 2) checks if any of them is true. In my version I check `if List.MatchesAny` and pass check-function (like Foxan Ng does)

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to return the string that matches, you can use the List.Accumulate function:

```
List.Accumulate(YOUR_LIST_OF_STRINGS, null, (state, current) => if Text.Contains([YOUR COLUMN NAME], current) then current else state)
```

The only disadvantage to this method is that if there are multiple matches it will return only the last...

Here's a more complex version that returns a list of the matched strings:

```
List.Accumulate(YOUR_LIST_OF_STRINGS, {}, (state, current) => if Text.Contains([YOUR COLUMN NAME], current) then List.Combine({{current}, state}) else state)
```

Or you could amend that so that it returns a comma delimited list as a string etc., or whatever.