# Power Query filtering records based on a list of IDs

Tags: sql, list, select, powerquery, m

I'm trying to select a subset of data. I have an `[ID]` column, and a list of the IDs I want from it.  My thought is to use Table.SelectRows(), but I'm not sure how to get my IDs into the second argument.  Any ideas?

If it helps, I'm basically trying to do the equivalent of the SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE [ID] in (list)
```

Comment: Most basically, create a table from your ID list, and then merge one table against the other on the ID field, and filter out rows with no matches

Comment: Related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070454)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740679).